# What does this kind of http header mean in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony1, http-headers

```
$this->getResponse()->addCacheControlHttpHeader('private=True');
```

What's that for,how does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.1

> private:
>
> Indicates that all or part of the
>   response message is intended for a
>   single user and MUST NOT be cached by
>   a shared cache. This allows an origin
>   server to state that the specified
>   parts of the response are intended for
>   only one user and are not a valid
>   response for requests by other users.
>   A private (non-shared) cache MAY cache
>   the response. Note: This usage of the
>   word private only controls where the
>   response may be cached, and cannot
>   ensure the privacy of the message
>   content.

Comment: How can the browser identify different users?

Comment: It can't. These headers are intended to provide info to proxy servers, which serve multiple users, as opposed to a browser which only serves one. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) Regular browsers simply ignore it since they don't care about multiple users.

Answer (score 0):

It's related with the [cache control directive](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html).

By default, pages protected with HTTP authentication are considered private; they will not be kept by shared caches. However, you can make authenticated pages public with a Cache-Control: public header; HTTP 1.1-compliant caches will then allow them to be cached.